DataTables SSP Class Unable to Set Condition
I'm using the DataTables SSP class. According to my research on the internet, it should be sufficient to add SSP::simple to the end in order to write a where condition. However, I've tried it and it still fetches all the data, the condition doesn't seem to work.
My code is below:
// Veritabanı bağlantı bilgilerini içeren bir dizi oluşturun
$dbDetails = array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'db'   => 'sigortav2-1',
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => ''
);
// Veritabanı bağlantısını sağlayın
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbDetails['host'] . ';dbname=' . $dbDetails['db'], $dbDetails['user'], $dbDetails['pass']);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Veritabanı bağlantısı kurulamadı: " . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
// SSP sınıfını kullanarak DataTables için gereken veri kaynağını oluşturun
$table = 'ihbarlar';
$primaryKey = 'id';
$columns = array(
    array('db' => 'id',         'dt' => 0),
    array('db' => 'ekleme_tarihi',       'dt' => 1),
    array('db' => 'ekleyen_bayi',   'dt' => 2),
    array('db' => 'sigorta_sirketi',   'dt' => 3),
    array('db' => 'plakasi',     'dt' => 4),
    array('db' => 'dosya_numarasi',     'dt' => 5),
    array('db' => 'sigortali_ad_soyad',     'dt' => 6),
    array('db' => 'durum',     'dt' => 7),
    array(
        'db' => 'id',
        'dt' => 8,
        'formatter' => function ($id, $row) {
            return '<div class="dropdown"><button class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">İşlem <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-down"></i></button><div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton "><a class="dropdown-item" href="ihbar/ihbar-bilgileri/' . $id . '">Gör/Düzenle</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript<b></b>:void(0);">Yazdır</a><div class="dropdown-divider"></div><a class="dropdown-item text-danger" href="javascript<b></b>:void(0);">Sil</a></div></div>';
        }
    ),
    array('db' => 'arac_modeli',     'dt' => 9),
);
// WHERE koşulunu oluşturun
$where = "bayi_id = 'yazılım'";
// SSP sınıfını kullanarak DataTables için gereken veri kaynağını oluşturun
require_once 'SSP.class.php'; // SSP sınıfının dosyasının yolunu doğru şekilde ayarlayın
echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple($_GET, $db, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $where)
);
exit;

According to my research on the internet, it should be sufficient to add SSP::simple to the end in order to write a where condition
